# Exporting dictionary data to a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a dictionary data type in Python:

```
selecteddatas = random.sample(numbers, 100)
    for data in selecteddatas:
        calls = random.choice(range(600))
        a[data] = {'time_stamp': str_now, 'calls': calls}
```

and I am trying to export it to a csv file, but its not working. Can anyone suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Show the code you're using to try to export to csv.

Answer (score 0):

A list of dicts with the same keys can be easily converted to a pandas DataFrame. These can then be easily converted to a csv.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(a).to_csv(filepath,index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `pandas`, using `csv.DictWriter`:

```
import random, csv, datetime

selecteddatas = random.sample(list(range(100)), 100)
a = {}
for data in selecteddatas:
    calls = random.choice(range(600))
    a[data] = {'time_stamp': datetime.datetime.now(), 'calls': calls}

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['time_stamp', 'calls'])

    writer.writeheader()
    for k in a.keys():
        writer.writerow(a[k])
```

The data.csv contains:

```
time_stamp,calls
2018-07-24 17:54:01.989054,273
2018-07-24 17:54:01.989059,290
2018-07-24 17:54:01.989062,51
2018-07-24 17:54:01.989064,188
2018-07-24 17:54:01.989067,518
...and so on.
```